# How can I get file info from the "Statistics" tab?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Windows 7 x64; C#

Look screens below, please:

[image]

[image]

How can I get Created\Modified DateTime from the "Statistics" tab (via C#)?
I tried the `File.GetCreationTime()` and the `FileInfo.CreationTime`, but this are the info from the "General" tab.

Thank you.

Comment: Well it's AutoCAD-specific information (i.e you will only see that tab if you have AutoCAD installed) so it wouldn't be available using the normal classes. Have you tried finding out if they have any C# libraries?

Comment: Created at `17:24:35`, but modified `17:21:53`? So it was modified before it was created?

Comment: @Matt If you modify a file, and then copy it to new location, modified time will be earlier than created time for the new file.

Comment: @Tilak: Ah. Fair point.

Comment: @Matt Burland I created some Drawing1.dwg, which is a new DWG document, created on a basis DWT template. Then I created its a copy and named it as Drawing2.dwg.

Comment: It is strange, but information is shown exactly so.